# Как правильно сохранить информацию в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть сайт, на нем зарегистрированный пользователь может делать покупки, скажем покупать жетоны, каждый жетон по своему уникальный, список видов жетонов храниться в отдельной таблице базы данных. Встал вопрос, как правильно сохранить список купленных игроком жетонов, чтобы при необходимости, например на странице профиля отображать их? У меня в голове 2 варианта:

1. Просто сделать ещё одну таблицу с колонками: **iDПользователя**, **IDЖетона**, **КоличествоКупленныхЖетонов**? И при покупке каждого жетона проверять, если такой жетон уже покупался пользователем, то увеличивать кол-во купленных, если же не покупался, то добавлять новую запись в таблицу.
2. Сделать таблицу с колонками: **iDПользователя**, **КупленныеЖетоны**. В этом случае, колонка **КупленныеЖетоны** будет содержать строку с разделителями, которую потом можно будет распарсить в массив. Например что-то типа такого:
   "12_3;24_1". Т.е. по такому шаблону **IDЖетона_КолВоЖетоновКупленных**.

Как это делают нормальные люди?)

Comment: *Как это делают нормальные люди?* Нормальные люди любую денормализацию стараются забыть как страшный сон. Если это сделать - останется только вариант номер один.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант звучит куда убедительнее чем второй. Но суммировать не надо. Вы в этой табличке просто фиксируете транзакции.

Можно еще добавить столбцы: дату покупки, IP при совершении покупки, сумму которую потратил и кучу полезных няшностей, в будущем могут пригодиться.

Когда понадобится вывести кол-во, то просто составите соответствующий запрос, чтобы он сам там за вас все посчитал :)

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю)

Comment: Думаю, тут "суммирование" не нужно сохранять в таблице, так как по вашим же словам, эти жетоны "уникальные". В другом случае (например, джинсы в интернет-магазине) это поле присутствовать должно. Мне кажется, это было важно для уточнения :) Вообще, если говорить про интернет-магазин, то там все намного сложнее по архитектуре будет. Так что это другая история...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так (называется «нормализацией» БД). Таблица пользователей, где хранятся их ID (это поле автоинкремент), и любые другие данные о пользователе. Таблица Жетонов — ID жетона — автоинкремент, другие поля содержат название и ещё что-там нужно.

Третья таблица — связующая: id (автоинкремент — он сам работает), IDПользователя, IDЖетона. По этой таблице вы можете узнать какие жетоны получил пользователь, и их количество.

Comment: То что вы описали, называется реализацией `М-М`, что в свою очередь можно отнести к термину `нормализации`. Но в `М-М` не нужен автоинкремент(в третьей таблице). По связующей табличке в `М-М` не считают кол-во (а то получается если 10штук купил 10 записей будет?), нет, она нужна для других целей. Конкретно тут у автора - логирование транзакций, назвать это `M-M` скорей нельзя, чем можно (но чуть чуть можно), ибо индексы имеют другой смысл как и табличка в целом.